# How do i shuffle checklistbox?

Tags: vb.net

I want to shuffle the questions in the textboxes with the answers in the checklistboxes. The problem is textboxes do shuffle but the checklistboxes doesnt.

```
    Dim txtQ() As TextBox = {txtQ1, txtQ2, txtQ3, txtQ4, txtQ5, txtQ6, txtQ7, txtQ8, txtQ9, txtQ10}
    Dim cbA() As CheckedListBox = {cbA1, cbA2, cbA3, cbA4, cbA5, cbA6, cbA7, cbA8, cbA9, cbA10} 
     While r.Read
        If i <= 9 Then

            txtQ(i).Text = r.GetString("exam_question")
            cbA(i).Items.Clear()
            cbA(i).Items.Add("a) " & r.GetString("exam_ans_a"))
            cbA(i).Items.Add("b) " & r.GetString("exam_ans_b"))
            cbA(i).Items.Add("c) " & r.GetString("exam_ans_c"))
            cbA(i).Items.Add("d) " & r.GetString("exam_ans_d"))

            i = i + 1
        End If
    End While
    Dim n As Integer = i - 1
    Randomize()
    While i > 0
        Dim j As Integer = CInt(Int(n * Rnd()))
        i = i - 1
        Dim tmpQ As String = txtQ(i).Text
        txtQ(i).Text = txtQ(j).Text
        txtQ(j).Text = tmpQ
        Dim tmpA As CheckedListBox = cbA(i)
        cbA(i) = cbA(j)
        cbA(j) = tmpA
    End While
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [random and shuffle questions vb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634541/random-and-shuffle-questions-vb)

Comment: Dont post dups its not good practice. You accepted the other question whats the problem youre having now? If the other didnt help why did you accept it. Posting dup questions wont get you anywhere further here...

Comment: im very sorry about that, it wont happen again

Comment: Shuffle txtQ first, use Random instead of Rnd(), then post the shuffled result in the control.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a value-type property in case of TextBoxes and a reference-type in case of CheckBoxes. You should rather swap the Text of those CheckedListBox Items to let it behave properly. Simply assigning one CheckBox Item's reference to another CheckBox Item doesn't do any good.